# Can you re-use a function's JSDoc on a re-declaration of the function in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

This is rather nitpicky, but I'm really curious if there's some way to do this in TypeScript.

I have a function `addUser()` in my Electron-TypeScript project. This function exists in a separate file, which imports into the **main** process. Then, the main process exposes the function to the IPC bridge, which allows me to access it in the **preload**, which then gets exposed to the renderer. Here's what that looks like:

**dbinteract.ts**

```
/** 
 * Adds a new user to the database.
 * @param {AddUserProps} userinfo An object containing all user info besides `id`.
 * @returns The new UserData object from database, including `id`.
 * */
function addUser(userinfo: AddUserProps) { ...code... }
```

**index.ts (main)**

```
import { app, ipcMain } from 'electron';
import dbinteract from './dbfunc/dbinteract'

app.on('ready', () => {
  ipcMain.handle('db:addUser', (event, userinfo: AddUserProps) => dbinteract.addUser(userinfo))
});
```

**preload.ts**

```
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require('electron')

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('dbfunc', {
    addUser: (userinfo: AddUserProps) => ipcRenderer.invoke('db:addUser', userinfo),
});
```

Notice the **JSDoc** above the function declaration in **dbinteract.ts**.
See, because of the nature of the IPC bridge, I have to re-declare the `addUser` function inside of **preload.ts**. Since it is re-declared, i lose the JSDoc documentation when using the re-declared function inside of the preload/renderer.

Is there any method within TypeScript to separate the JSDoc documentation from the function declaration, so that I could have that documentation available when using the function, without just copy/pasting it? I'd like to have a single source of truth for the JSDoc that applies to both somehow.

Comment: I use IntelliJ and in similar situations what I do is put a JSDoc comment like this: `/** @see addUser */` -- IntelliJ will recognize that as a real reference to `addUser` and give you tooltip docs to it https://recordit.co/z5Zi1jYZ6v

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar use case, although not specific to electron.

I just assert the type of the re-declared function as if it were the original function itself, so in your case it could be something like:

```
import type { addUser } from "./path/to/dbinteract";

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('dbfunc', {
    addUser: ((userinfo: AddUserProps) => ipcRenderer.invoke('db:addUser', userinfo)) as typeof addUser,
});
```

The key is that the re-declared version must have the *exact same signature*.

Note that such remote call is very probably asynchronous, so to be consistent, the `addUser` function must also be async / return a `Promise`. In some cases, I have to declare my function as `async` just for that, even though its code is entirely synchronous...